# Removing panel title after collapse

Tags: extjs

I have been using Ext-Js 5 and my application is using border layout. When the west pane is collapsed, I need to remove the title of the panel that appears in vertical direction on the panel.

I tried several options (panel.getHeader.title.destroy(), panel.getHeader.setVisible(false) ) but nothing worked for me  .

Can someone please help me with the same ?

Thanks in advance

samir

Comment: panel.getPlaceholder().remove(1) is the key to it.

Comment: If you are trying to remove only the title, panel.setTitle("") should do on collapse..